# Is it possible to add easily a widget from CRUD listing on backpack laravel dashboard?

Tags: widget, crud, dashboard, laravel-backpack

I want to add a simple list from a CRUD of my admin into my dashboard.

Here's my exact use case:
I have a to-do list system managed by CRUD.

I want to display a condensed or full view of filtered data on the dashboard.

Is there any way to leverage CRUD functionality without reworking the entire table system to integrate it into my dashboard?

I search on documentation any way to do that, but not found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Backpack has no list widget available as of now. It is on our TODO list.

You can create a widget for your needs with basic steps:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/base-widgets#creating-a-custom-widget-type-1

OR

I know a package which has a table widget. Try, it may work for you(i never tested it):

https://github.com/izica/relations-widgets-for-backpack?tab=readme-ov-file#relation-table